# how can I use the id of textbox with ckeditor (using with ajax)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

[image]I have used the CKEditor for my textbox styling .i have done to add in my textbox but if I want to get my id from the textbox then it gives the undefined value . Anyone can help me to resolve my query it would be helpful for me.

```js
      <script src="//cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/standard/ckeditor.js">     </script>  
          <script>  CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1' );  </script>        
         <script>
               $(document).ready(function(){

            var topic_describe=$("#add_val").html();
      alert(topic_describe);
               
                });
          </script>
```

```html
  <textarea name="editor1" id="add_val"></textarea>
  <br/>
 <a href='#' class="btn btn-success" style=' padding-top:10px;'   id='submit' ><strong><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>&nbsp;Add Post </strong></a>
```

as you can see in image after click the button the output is undefined .

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you are trying to achieve here: do u want the textarea's `id` or its inside contents. There is no image attached, nor any action is defined on the `add post` link/button.

Comment: who is using down vote in my post ?.please tell me

Comment: actually, I want contents of the Textarea and used to redirect on another page by using  ajax .

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine. Just verify below points:

1. You are loading the `jquery.js` and `ckeditor.js` before you are using them, preferably in the `<head>`
2. Textarea `id` is the same as in your JS

If so, are you missing any other details which might be relevant?

Check out:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  CKEDITOR.replace('editor1');
  var topic_describe = $("#add_val").html();
  alert(topic_describe);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.5.11/standard/ckeditor.js">
</script>
<textarea name="editor1" id="add_val">************* This is the Text inside the Textarea *************</textarea>
<br/>
<a href='#' class="btn btn-success" style=' padding-top:10px;' id='submit'><strong><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pencil'></span>&nbsp;Add Post </strong></a>
```

Comment: basically, I wanted to  find out the editor id regardless of text area 'id'

Comment: Aren't editor and textarea the same? Can u give an example for your code?